# Set invalid for json web token when we do not use it any more

Tags: node.js, token, access-token, json-web-token

I am using [JsonWebToken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) to auth for user. When user login I create a token for user. Then user update their information, I create a new token for user. How can I set invalid for previous token?. Ex: Change expired date to now or something else....

Answer (score 0):

To invalidate the previous token, you might want to use a  database or a datastore like Redis, which can contain blacklisted tokens. Each request's JWT can then be checked against this validated.

Comment: This is not a good idea, because we use token instead of session id to avoid using Redis

Comment: Can you also sign the JWT with a hash of the user information, then?